# How to hide butons when I open the excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three buttons and I want to have two of them hidden when I open the file. Any help would be great!

I tried setting the Visible value as false on the sheet, but it does nothing

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Formato As Worksheet
Set Formato = Worksheets("TH-F46")
Formato.Shapes("btnSubmit").Visible = False
Formato.Shapes("btnEdit").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You've put the code in the worksheet change event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A worksheet Change event runs when cells on the worksheet change

Use a Workbook_Open even instead

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Formato As Worksheet
Set Formato = Worksheets("TH-F46")
Formato.Shapes("btnSubmit").Visible = False
Formato.Shapes("btnEdit").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I could help